# TDictionary - invalid key

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, tdictionary

I have code like this:

```
type
  TMyDictionary = TDictionary<int, int>;

var
  myDict: TMyDictionary;
  k, v: integer;

  // code to fill the dictionary

  for k in myDict.Keys do
  begin
     v := myDict.Items[k];

     // other stuff
  end;
```

Randomly I see an exception thrown on 'v := myDict.Items[k];' which says k is invalid.

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at CodeCentral I see a number of bugs raised against TDictionary and in particular the enumerator that supports the for ... in ... construct.

Answer (score 1):

Are you modifying `myDict` inside the section labeled `// other stuff`?

Comment: I'm not modifying myDict inside the loop. I walk through each the dictionary to find the greatest value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce this problem in one single method with only local variables.

It could be that your using the variable from 2 different threads, or perhaps your updating the elements in the myDict.

I'll try to explain my answer about reproducing it more:

You should create one method which could run on another computer and show the error you're getting.

So for example (Question: I'm getting a divide by zero exception):

```
var
   i : integer;
begin
   i := 3;
   while (i <= 0) do
   begin
     Writeln(FloatToStr(20/i));
     Dec(i);
   end;
end
```

If you run this on a computer, people will get the divide by zero exception. So I was able to reproduce the problem. Try to create a snippet as simple as possible to reproduce in a consistent way the problem your having.

Comment: It is as you describe.  A single method.  Just one thread.  All I'm doing inside the loop is looking for the largest 'v' and storing this in a local variable.

Comment: What I meant was, try to make a sample procedure to reproduce it, and post that here so others can look at your sample code.

Comment: Here's the complete loop:
      for k in fcm.Keys do
      begin
        try
          v := fcm.Items[k];
          if v > max then
          begin
            Result := k;
            max := v;
          end;
        except
          Continue;
        end;
      end;